# Config data bindings in Input Autocomplete - ElementUI

Tags: element-ui

Default, attributes 'value' is key for binding value. And if i want to changes data bindings from 'value' to 'name', it not worked!

```
[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/vu_1995/qkf549vL/3/)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the key that `el-autocomplete` uses by specifying the attribute `value-key="name"`

Also, in your fiddle, you also have to make sure you're using `name` instead of value in the filter function:

```
  createFilter(queryString) {
      return (link) => {
          return (link.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryString.toLowerCase()) === 0);
      };
  },
```

Here's an updated fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/jmbldwn/tLyc7hxg/1/